# C++ if statements: first condition superseding the second - UB or well defined?

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++14

Being a moderate time coder, I saw things like the following many times:

```cpp
if (a != nullptr && a->data != nullptr) {
  // do something good with a and a->data
}
```

However, I never really referred to documentation regarding such a simple case.

---

To my mind, the following is happening:

- First, `a != nullptr` is checked
- Second, `a->data != nullptr` is checked

The thing now here is: if `a != nullptr` returns **false** and we have a conjunction via `&&` then there's **no point** to check the second statement `a->data != nullptr` being true or false:

since the first statement results in a false expression, the code inside the if-statement will not be executed, we don't need to check the second expression

---

But recently I have returned to the question yet again:

Is if safe to have a construction like this: `if (a != nullptr && a->data != nullptr) {}`? Can it happen so that both* statements are checked and what I get is the `nullptr` dereference?

*- no multi-threading involved

---

**What I'm asking is**: is the above situation has a well defined behavior (and where can I find documentation for that) or this is generally UB that must be avoided? Is the behavior any different depending on the operating system (say, Windows vs. Linux-based)?

Comment: Perfectly fine, fully defined

Comment: Google for short-circuited evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is safe

It's actually one of the few cases in which C++ guarantees the evaluation order; first the left-side is evaluated and then (and only if the left side is true) the second side is evaluated.

Comment: More importantly it's evaluated strictly according to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), so it's not always left to right. `a + b * c` is right (`b * c`) then left (`a + ...`). With a single `&&` it's left to right with short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: @tadman: you're confusing evaluation order with precedence... in `a() + b()*c()` the compiler is for example even free to generate code that will call `b()` first, then `a()`, then `c()` and that finally will compute the result.

Comment: A good point, but only because `+` and `*` don't short-circuit. I'm trying to think of an example where `&&` is involved but it's not strictly left-to-right because of precedence issues.

Comment: @tadman: `&&`, `||` and the ternary operator `?:` where in C++ the only ones guaranteeing evaluation order (and only when not overloaded). Later C++17 added a few others, for example `<<` and `>>` because it was very surprising for people that `std::cout << a() << b()` could call `b()` first.

Comment: Great examples!

Comment: I believe the comma operator also specifies operand evaluation order.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: sorry... you're right, of course the comma operator was also guaranteeing evaluation order. Now (17) there are quite a few more (e.g. `operator[]`)